# react-jsonschema-form: How to allow zeros for a required number property?

Tags: material-ui, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

In the "Numbers" example on https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/, if I enter a 0 in any field, the input is cleared. If I make the field required, it's now impossible to submit it with a value of 0.

How can I have a number property that is required but allows a 0 as value?

Edit: I noticed, the problem only appears when selecting the **material-ui** theme.

Comment: This sounds like a bug you should be reporting directly to that application/library.

Comment: @Ether Thanks. I just noticed the problem only appears with the material-ui theme. I'll debug it some more and will then create an issue.